# Cube.js vs DBT advantages disadvantages can I switch from using cube.js to DBT

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, dbt, cube.js

Currently the org I'm working for uses cube.js to query and show data on the frontend side. My question is can't I just transform the data with the help of DBT and directly just query the db to show the data on the frontend.

I'm trying to evaluate the use of DBT in the org and instead of using cube.js I think DBT would give more advantages like versioning the models and transforming the data for future use. To give a little background the org im working for hosts db for new clients. I wanted to know is there a way to version dbs. The current db we use is postgressql.